# Why doesn't this generic recognize its superclass boundary (Java)?

Tags: java, generics

I have a system of object instances that contain a reference to a definition object.  I have a top-level class for each inheritance tree.  The instance object has a generic reference to the corresponding definition class.

Using generics in the getter, a subclass of the top-level object can get the right type of definition without casting.  However, an abstract subclass that is subclassed again cannot:

```
class Def { }

abstract class Animal<D extends Def> {
    D def;
    D getDef() { return def; }
}

class CatDef extends Def { }
class Cat extends Animal<CatDef> { }

abstract class BearDef extends Def { }
abstract class Bear<D extends BearDef> extends Animal<D> { }

class BlackBearDef extends BearDef { }
class BlackBear extends Bear<BlackBearDef> { }

class AnimalDefTest {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        CatDef catDef = cat.getDef(); // CatDef works fine

        Bear bear = new BlackBear();
        BearDef bearDef = bear.getDef(); // Error: Expected Def not BearDef? Why???
        BearDef bearDef2 = ((Animal<BearDef>)bear).getDef(); // Works
    }
}
```

Why does `getDef` require a `Bear` to be cast to (`Animal<BearDef>`) to get a `BearDef`?  Bear is conclusively defined as `extends Animal<? extends BearDef>`.

[**Edit**] Even stranger, if I change the Bear class line:

```
abstract class Bear<D extends BearDef> extends Animal<BearDef> { }
```

(In which case D is unused and is irrelevant) it *still* doesn't work.  Erase D and the following line resolves the error in the code above (but doesn't help me do what I need to do with subclass definitions):

```
abstract class Bear extends Animal<BearDef> { }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using the raw type `Bear` when in fact it should be parameterized with a type of `BearDef`. If you wrote

```
Bear<BlackBearDef> bear = new BlackBear();
```

or

```
Bear<?> bear = new BlackBear();
```

it'd work fine.

Another thing: I'm not sure how you intend to use this, but it seems likely to me that you would be fine just doing this instead:

```
abstract class Bear extends Animal<BearDef> {}

class BlackBear extends Bear {
  // make use of covariant return type to make BlackBear return correct def
  @Override
  BlackBearDef getDef() { ... }
}
```

My reason for thinking this is that *if* you want a `Bear` whose `getDef()` method returns a `BlackBearDef`, that `Bear` reference would need to be parameterized as `Bear<BlackBearDef>`. In that case (for your example anyway) you effectively know that it's a `BlackBear` from the declared type, so you might as well just be referring to it as a `BlackBear`. That said, it's obviously not always so simple and your actual situation may not allow this.

Comment: That *sort of* makes sense, but since it knows that it is *at least* a BearDef, shouldn't it essentially assume what you have in the second line there?

Comment: @Renesis: You'd think so, but when you use the raw type, anything related to generics (that included) goes out the window. You should never use the raw form of a parameterized type except where you absolutely have to (which should be rarely to never).

Comment: @Renesis: No, it only knows it's at least a `Def`.  The erasure of `Bear<D extends BearDef> extends Animal<D>` is simply `Bear extends Animal`.  And the minimum bound for `Animal.getDef()` is simply a `Def`, not a `BearDef`.  Basically, once you start using raw types (types that were declared as parameterized but that you're not parameterizing at the point of usage), you've forfeited everything generics can give you and you fall back to the erased forms.

Comment: @Renesis: Raw types are confusing, since they only really exist as a hack for backwards compatibility with Java code that was written before generics existed.  In this case, there *should* be a compiler warning that warns you about using the raw type -- it's well worth paying attention to those.

Comment: @ColinD @Daniel Pryden thanks, I actually had no idea that I was making an implicit decision to use *raw types* by defining a Bear with no generic parameter. That also explains the problem in my edit example. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as posted by @Allen Parslow, a `<?>` will preserve the use of the *parameterized type* and solve my problem without having to tightly couple the classes by using the Def class on every instance declaration.

Comment: Updated to use just `<?>` rather than `<? extends BearDef>` since that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This will work too:

```
Bear<?> bear = new BlackBear();
```